# Helper methods and using the for loop correctly

Tags: java

**The guidelines for this program follow**

Problem B: Year Dates. Objectives: Understanding the Switch structure, helper methods, and using a While loop with a sentinel value.

You are to make a class called Year2012 to manipulate dates when given a month(mm), or a month plus a day(dd) as integer values. It has the following get methods: 1) MonthName which returns a String value that is the name of the Month, e.g. September, June, May, etc. 2) DaysInMonth which returns the number of days in the month. 3)DayOfTheYear which returns the ordinal year date (a number between 1-365, often called the Julian date). Hint, use a for loop to add the days in each prior month, and then add the current month's days. 4) DayOfWeek which returns a String value which is the name of the day, e.g. Monday, Tuesday, etc.

Some of these methods can be used as 'helper' methods for others. All methods will use a switch statement either directly or indirectly. Each method computes a return value from the values sent to it, therefore there are no class attributes, and only a default constructor. All logic must be contained in your own methods. (ie. You will not use existing API classes for your logic.)
Design a tester application that asks the user for a month and day, and then displays the name of the month, the number of days in the month, the day of the week for this date, and the Julian date for this day. Write your program to process dates using a While loop until a sentinel value is entered. Run your program multiple times to test out different days, but turn in a final run using the following five dates: Jan.1, Apr.18, Aug.2, Nov.28, & Dec.15.

**I'm having troubles with certain parts of this program. Specifically with the Julian date method and the dayofTheWeek method. Julian date keeps printing out a 1 (I haven't tested many dates), and is a helper method to the dayofTheWeek method, could you take a look at my code and see what my problem is?**

```
    public String monthName(int month)
    {
        String mon = null;
        switch (month)
        {
            case 1:
                mon = "January";
                break;
            case 2:
                mon = "February";
                break;
            case 3:
                mon = "March";
                break;
            case 4:
                mon = "April";
                break;
            case 5:
                mon = "May";
                break;
            case 6:
                mon = "June";
                break;
            case 7:
                mon = "July";
                break;
            case 8:
                mon = "August";
                break;
            case 9:
                mon = "September";
                break;
            case 10:
                mon = "October";
                break;
            case 11:
                mon = "November";
                break;
            case 12:
                mon = "December";
                break;
            default:
                mon = "Inccorect entry";
                break;
        }
        return mon;
    }

    public int daysInMonth(int month)
    {
        int days = 0;
        switch (month)
        {
            case 1:
                days = 31;
                break;
            case 2:
                days = 28;
                break;
            case 3:
                days = 31;
                break;
            case 4:
                days = 30;
                break;
            case 5:
                days = 31;
                break;
            case 6:
                days = 30;
                break;
            case 7:
                days = 31;
                break;
            case 8:
                days = 31;
                break;
            case 9:
                days = 30;
                break;
            case 10:
                days = 31;
                break;
            case 11:
                days = 30;
                break;
            case 12:
                days = 31;
                break;
            default:
                days = 0;
        }
        return days;
    }

    public int dayOfTheYear(int month, int day)
    {
        int julian = 0;
        for (int count = 1; count == month; count++)
        {
            julian += daysInMonth(count);
        }
        return julian;
    }

    public String dayOfWeek(int month, int day)
    {
        int daysSoFar = dayOfTheYear(month, day);
        int weekDay = daysSoFar % 7;
        String dayName = null;

        switch (weekDay)
        {   
            case 1:
                dayName = "Sunday";
                break;
            case 2:
                dayName = "Monday";
                break;
            case 3:
                dayName = "Tuesday";
                break;
            case 4:
                dayName = "Wednesday";
                break;
            case 5:
                dayName = "Thursday";
                break;
            case 6:
                dayName = "Friday";
                break;
            case 7:
                dayName = "Saturday";
                break;
            default:
                dayName = "Incorrect entry";
        }
        return dayName;     
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Year2012 year = new Year2012();
        System.out.println("Please enter a month using integers (Jan = 1): ");
        int month = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter a day within that month: ");
        int day = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Month: " + year.monthName(month));
        System.out.println("Number of days in month: " + year.daysInMonth(month));
        System.out.println("Day of the week: " + year.dayOfWeek(month, day));
        System.out.println("Julian date: " + year.dayOfTheYear(month, day));

    }
}
```

Comment: @jzworkman: please do not add the tag "homework" to questions; it's obsolete and is being removed.

Comment: @Wooble I had no idea, and until it is removed how would I know that?  Is there a discussion as to why this is being done somewhere?  I know the community looks down on directly doing homework for people so I am curious how this will work going forward.

Comment: @jzworkman: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag (it's also in the tag wiki for the tag). When you go to add the tag it should pop up the description that mentions it's obsolete.

Comment: @Wooble Thank you for the link.  Based on that discussion, shouldnt this question then be closed as not a real question/too centralized(since it is really only of benefit to the person asking the question).

Answer (score 3):

You got it wrong in the for loop setting the julian value. Try this:

```
int julian = 0;
for (int count = 1; count < month; count++)
{
julian += daysInMonth(count);
}
return julian + day;
```

This loop uses **count < month** instead of **count == month**. It also returns **julian + day**.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple issues in the julian value calculation. Try this:

```
public int dayOfTheYear(int month, int day)
{
    int julian = 0;
    for (int count = 1; count < month; count++) //note this loop will not run for Jan(as the logic below will cover that
    {
        julian += daysInMonth(count);
    }
    julian += day;
    return julian;
}
```

This loop uses count < month instead of count == month, and then adds the days from the input before returning the answer.

note this loop will not run for Jan as in that case you just want to add the days entered.

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop condition is `count == month`.

```
public int dayOfTheYear(int month, int day)
{
    int julian = 0;
    for (int count = 1; count == month; count++)
    {
        julian += daysInMonth(count);
    }
    return julian;
}
```

This means the loop body will only execute when the `month` input is 1, and then only once.  Did you mean `count < month`?

Comment: Don't forget to add the number of days in the current month.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I meant Bill, thank you! and Marvo, just added that part once I figured out the loop part, Thank you for the reminder. Silly errors...

Comment: @user2089277 Yes, Marvo is right. If you add the day in from the current month, then I think you want to use `<` instead of `<=`.